# Ruby Rake task API Timeout error

Tags: ruby, api, email, timeout

I have a fairly general question. I have written a fairly large rake task that goes through several API calls. On each API call I have written a fail safe like

```
if response.code != 200
    Email.delete
```

So that works without any issue - If any API call throughout the entire script gives a response code of anything other than 200 it will abort. However, out of 100 times it seems like at least 1-2 times I get a timeout error. The script will freeze up for some time and then throw a timeout error.

How can I escape that timeout error and make sure my script is running Email.delete if the script times out at any point?

The big picture is my script is creating ~10,000 emails. If it times out halfway, I don't want to have to resend all ~10,000 emails. I would rather delete all of the emails and start over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `rescue` from a timeout error.

```
def do_rake_task
  # work goes here...
  # I hope it isn't scraping email addresses for spam...
rescue Timeout::Error => e
  # log #{e} for later, maybe
  Email.delete
end
```

Comment: `rescue`, that'll do it. I'm sending emails based on content in a content file, no spam checking. Thanks for the help.